# Nunit test case is not shown as covered in NCover

Tags: ncover

Let me know the reason for the below question.
I have written NUnit test and is going through all lines of that method in debug mode, but those lines are not shown as covered in NCover report.

Note: I am getting the data for that method from DB.

I am using completev.3.4.18.6937 version ncover and executing nunits using command line \ using ncover UI.

Comment: Can you share more details? - What version of NCover are you using? - What command are you using to run NCover and/or to run the NUnit tests? Command-line? or another method?

Comment: Are you missing the `.pdb` file of the assembly under test?